# SOAPAction and servicestack

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, soap, servicestack

don't know if you can help a poor befuddled c# programmer, but here goes. I have a client with a legacy Java Soap app that we need to accept incoming Soap requests from. I have built a solution and tested it and all is well.

When I let the Java app loose on the ASMX file, it fails because I cannot for the life of me get my code to accept the soap action needs to be understood at my end.

The soap action sent is by the Java is:

> urn:mycode:uk:gi:dis:supplierenmanager:v02:SupplierManager:AppointManager

Whereas I have used the following against the class that is created when a new web service is added:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="urn:mycode:uk:gy:dis:suppliermanager:v02:SupplierManager:")>
```

Then on the method, I have added:

```
<WebMethod(MessageName:="AppointSupplier")>
```

This works apart from one little problem. The combination of the above provides the following soap action:

> urn:mycode:uk:gi:dis:supplierenmanager:v02:SupplierManager:/AppointManager

As you can see, I am getting an extra forward slash and thus the soap action is rejected.

Does anyone know a work around, or if I am better off using WCF now?

If the answer is USE WCF DUMMY, that is fine and would willing accept that as an answer,  but if that IS the case, can someone please point me in the direction of some samples that will explain how to deal with SOAP headers and the dreaded SOAPAction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can't see a solution to this, but now looking at converting code from ASMX web service to WCF service that consumes soap.

This is because if I create an empty asp.net site and add a wcf service, I can add the following code to the function declaration in the interface code:

```
<OperationContract
(Action:="urn:mycode:uk:gi:dis:supplierenmanager:v02:SupplierManager:AppointManager")> _
```

This DOES create the correct SOAPAction.